# $ \mathbb{C} $-characters of $ A_5 $

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

How can we find all of five irreducible $ \mathbb{C} $-characters of $ A_5 $?
Precisely how can we construct the character table with the aid of orthogonality relations?

Comment: How much do you know about character tables?For instance,Do you know the size of Character table of $A_5$?

Comment: could you list at least one of the characters? Also could you list the conjugacy classes?

Comment: Do you know some representations of $S_5$?

Comment: I know a little.

Comment: This is a strange question. There are $5$ irreducible characters of $A_5$, so why are asking how to find $3$ of them? You will get more help if you supply more context.